# JSON from (RIOT) API Formatted Incorrectly

Tags: python, json, api, riot-games-api

I am importing JSON data into Python from an API and ran into the following decode error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Looking at online examples its immediately clear my JSON data has `'` where others have have `"`.

Ideally, I'd like to know why it's being downloaded in this way. It seems highly likely its an error on my end, not theirs.

I decided it should be easy to correct the JSON format but I have failed here too. Please see the below code for how I obtain the JSON data and my attempt at fixing it.

```
#----------------------------------------
#---Read this only if you want to download 
#---the data yourself. 
#----------------------------------------

#Built from 'Towards Data Science' guide
#https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-riot-api-with-python-b93be82dbbd6

#Must first have installed riotwatcher

#Info in my example is made up, I can't supply a real API code or
#I get in trouble. Sorry about this. You could obtain one from their website
#but this would be a lot of faff for what is probably a simple StackOverflow
#question

#If you were to get/have a key you could use the following information:
#<EUW> for region
#<Agurin> for name

#----------------------------------------
#---Code
#----------------------------------------


#--->Set Variables


#Get installed riotwatcher module for
#Python
import riotwatcher

#Import riotwatcher tools.
from riotwatcher import LolWatcher, ApiError

#Import JSON (to read the JSON API file)
import json

# Global variables
# Get new API from
# https://developer.riotgames.com/
api_key = 'RGAPI-XXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'
watcher = LolWatcher(api_key)
my_region = 'MiddleEarth'

#need to give path to where records
#are to be stored
records_dir = "/home/solebaysharp/Projects/Riot API/Records"


#--->Obtain initial data, setup new varaibles

#Use 'watcher' to get basic stats and setup my account as a variable (me)
me = watcher.summoner.by_name(my_region, "SolebaySharp")

# Setup retrieval of recent match info
my_matches = watcher.match.matchlist_by_account(my_region, me["accountId"])
print(my_matches)

#--->Download the recent match data

#Define where the JSON data is going to go
recent_matches_index_json = (records_dir + "/recent_matches_index.json")

#get that JSON data
print ("Downloading recent match history data")
file_handle = open(recent_matches_index_json,"w+")
file_handle.write(str(my_matches))
file_handle.close()

#convert it to python
file_handle = open(recent_matches_index_json,)
recent_matches_index = json.load(file_handle)
```

Except this giver the following error...

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

So instead to correct this I tried:

```
file_handle = open(recent_matches_index_json)

json_sanitised = json.loads(file_handle.replace("'", '"'))
```

This returns...

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

For the sake of completeness, beneath is a sample of what the JSON looks like. I have added the paragraphs to enhance readability. It does not come this way.

```
{'matches': [
  {'platformId': 'NA1',
   'gameId': 5687555181,
   'champion': 235,
   'queue': 400,
   'season': 13,
   'timestamp': 1598243995076,
   'role': 'DUO_SUPPORT',
   'lane': 'BOTTOM'
   },
   {'platformId': 'NA1',
   'gameId': 4965733458,
   'champion': 235,
   'queue': 400,
   'season': 13,
   'timestamp': 1598240780841,
   'role': 'DUO_SUPPORT',
   'lane': 'BOTTOM'
   },
   {'platformId': 'NA1',
   'gameId': 4583215645,
   'champion': 111,
   'queue': 400,
   'season': 13,
   'timestamp': 1598236666162,
   'role': 'DUO_SUPPORT',
   'lane': 'BOTTOM'
   }],
'startIndex': 0,
'endIndex': 100,
'totalGames': 186}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is occurring because Python is converting the JSON to a string (`str`).

```
file_handle.write(str(my_matches))
```

As it doesn't see the difference between `'` and `"` it just goes with its default of `'`.

We can stop this from happening by using `JSON.dumps`. This partially (certainly not fully) answers the second part of the question as well, as we're using a correctly formatted JSON command.

The above-mentioned line simply has to be replaced with this:

```
file_handle.write(json.dumps(my_matches))
```

This will preserve the JSON formatting.